# mptopdf: Is multipage output (PDF) possible?

Tags: metapost

I have this MetaPost input file:

```
%@ Maxime Chupin
%@ 4 février 2017
%@ animCercle.mp

prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "svg/%j-%c.svg";
outputformat := "svg";

% unité
u:=1cm;
%rayon cercle
r:=5u;

% nombre de quartier
numeric n;
n := 16;

% l'origine
pair O;
O :=(0,0);


% le fond
picture fond;
numeric angle;
fond = image(
  fill fullcircle scaled 2r withcolor black;
  for i:= 0 upto n-1:
  angle := (360.0/n)*i;
  draw (-r*cosd(angle),-r*sind(angle)) -- (r*cosd(angle),r*sind(angle)) withcolor white;
endfor;
);

% les balles
% rayon balle
rb := 0.3u;
def balle =
  fullcircle scaled 2rb
enddef;

% les différentes images
for j:= 0 upto 359:
  beginfig(j);
    draw fond;
    for i:=0 upto n-1:
      angle := (360.0/n)*i;
      fill balle shifted ((r-rb)*sind(angle+j),0) rotatedaround(O,angle) withcolor white;
    endfor;
  endfig;
endfor;
end.
```

As is, it produces a set of numbered SVG files if I run `mptopdf` on it. Now I want `mptopdf` to output multipage PDF with one animation frame per page.

Is that possible without writing a wrapper (La)TeX file?

I want to use the PDF as input for building a standalone animated SVG, using the `animate` package.

For output in PDF format I modified the following lines of the input file:

```
%outputtemplate := "svg/%j-%c.svg";
%outputformat := "svg";
outputformat := "pdf";
```

Currently, I only get a set of numbered PDF files.

Comment: “Is that possible without writing a wrapper (La)TeX file?” You are aware the `mptopdf` actually calls TeX?

Comment: No, I was not. Mpost yes, but TeX not.

Comment: Well yes, it does.  `mptopdf` is just a short [Perl script which calls `pdftex`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/38a9804bf0448f3c987903d2601175f1750e9fe3/scripts/context/perl/mptopdf.pl#L124-L133) with the format specified by [`mptopdf.tex`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/38a9804bf0448f3c987903d2601175f1750e9fe3/tex/generic/context/mptopdf/mptopdf.tex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `mptopdf.tex` format to implement your own version of `mptopdf`.  First I process your MetaPost file with `mpost`.  Here the full file again for reference.

```
%@ Maxime Chupin
%@ 4 février 2017
%@ animCercle.mp

prologues := 3;
%outputtemplate := "svg/%j-%c.svg";
%outputformat := "svg";
outputformat := "pdf";

% unité
u:=1cm;
%rayon cercle
r:=5u;

% nombre de quartier
numeric n;
n := 16;

% l'origine
pair O;
O :=(0,0);


% le fond
picture fond;
numeric angle;
fond = image(
  fill fullcircle scaled 2r withcolor black;
  for i:= 0 upto n-1:
  angle := (360.0/n)*i;
  draw (-r*cosd(angle),-r*sind(angle)) -- (r*cosd(angle),r*sind(angle)) withcolor white;
endfor;
);

% les balles
% rayon balle
rb := 0.3u;
def balle =
  fullcircle scaled 2rb
enddef;

% les différentes images
for j:= 0 upto 359:
  beginfig(j);
    draw fond;
    for i:=0 upto n-1:
      angle := (360.0/n)*i;
      fill balle shifted ((r-rb)*sind(angle+j),0) rotatedaround(O,angle) withcolor white;
    endfor;
  endfig;
endfor;
end.
```

This gives me files `test.<n>` where `n` is a number between 0 and 359.  Then I use the following TeX file to process everything into one single PDF document.

**`test.tex`**

```
% mptopdf uses \everypar to scan arguments.  Clear it.
\everypar{}

% \processMPfile uses \bye but we only want \eject
\def\bye{\eject}

% The argument of \processMPfile is delimited by space which is really
% inconvenient at times.  Make it well behaved instead.
\def\MPpage#1{\processMPfile #1 }

% Loop over all the MP files
\count0=0
\loop\ifnum\count0<360
  \MPpage{test.\the\count0}
  \advance\count0 by 1
\repeat

\end
```

The file is processed with `pdftex --fmt=mptopdf test.tex`.

Then I converted the resulting PDF to an animated GIF.

```
convert -density 40 test.pdf -delay 1 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove test.gif
```

[image]

Comment: `\pdfinfo` seems not to work here. Is there a simple way to add some info ?